# How do I make a variable equal the number returned by a function?

Tags: c++

I'm new to functions and I can't seem to figure out how to make a variable in a function return as a variable in main();

When I do:

```
int menu()
{
cin >> select;
return (select);
}

int main()
{
int x = menu;
return 0;
}
```

I get "invalid conversion from 'int (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

This code has also been very simplified but that's the idea, how do I get this variable to equal the value that my function has returned?

Comment: By reading a beginner C++ tutorial.

Comment: `int x = menu();`  Declare `int select;` in `menu()` You're Welcome !

Comment: You should read [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It list books you might need.

Comment: #include <iostream>

int value(){
 int select = 4;
 return select;
}

int main()
{
 int x = value();
 std::cout<<x;
  return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

```
int menu()   
{
   int select;
   cin >> select;
   return select;
}

int main()
{
   int x = menu();
   return 0;
}
```

1. Declare `select` before using it.
2. Add `()` to the call to `menu`.
3. (optional) remove the unnecessary parentheses around `select` in the `return` statement.